# Problem with nio4r gem: An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi everyone I have just started using ruby ​​on rails I have a problem when I go to effect "bundle update" gives me this error:

> "An error occurred while installing nio4r (1.2.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
> Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '1.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
> "In Gemfile:
> devise_token_auth was resolved to 0.1.40, which depends on
> rails was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
> actioncable was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
> nio4r
>
> Ruby version:2.3.0

I tried to run various commands like:

> bundle config build.nio4r --with-cflags="-std=c99"
> brew update

but they didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Seems like that gem does not support Ruby version 2.3.0

https://github.com/socketry/nio4r#supported-platforms

Also, probably a good idea to have a ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm.